# Load other page HTML inside page or DIV element

Tags: jquery, css, html, iframe

Ok what i want is to load outside HTML page inside main page and display it's content inside main page DIV. 
I know this is possible with IFRAME but looking for any other possible solution. Have some problems with 
loading IFRAMES with new version of Firefox. Content is not displayed and some users reports problems.

So whats the other option(s)? The good thing about IFRAMES is that other page is loaded separately. 
So even if this other website which is loaded in IFRAME contains same CSS classes etc. everything is displayed 
as it should be. So any good alternative to IFRAMES?

I am not really JQuery specialist but i find this option:

`$("#target_div").load("other_page.html");`

Looks nice but if both pages (parent and other_page.html) contains same CSS classes, selector etc. then in my case CSS from "other_page.html" is taking effect. Any possible solution (beside IFRAME)?

Basically i want to display other_page.html HTML content into parent page div without causing problems with CSS and other things on both pages (parent and other_page).

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: By the way if there are no real possible solution then maybe anyone know how to include IFRAME without causing problems with new browsers like Firefox etc. Iframe is very good option if it works in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**: No.

---

For importing another document *without* applying the CSS from the parent document to the child document and vice versa there is nothing better than an iframe.

If you use jQuery's `load` with a [page fragment](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) — `$("#target_div").load("other_page.html #some_id");` — then you could avoid the child page's CSS applying to the parent page (unless there is a `<style>` element in an invalid place) — but this eliminates the child page's CSS entirely (except for style attributes) and doesn't stop the parent page's CSS from applying to the page.

Using `<object data="foo.html"></object>` will have a similar effect to an iframe, but with weaker browser support and less consistent JavaScript APIs.

Using full frames will have a similar effect to an iframe, but requires a top level frameset document consisting only of frames. Frames are not supported in HTML 5.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. Yeah iframes are nice and best solution i agree. Just browser support is a problem. Like i said i was hoping for any easy work around. But not sure if exist. I am not very keen with Jquery so i was hoping there are any possible solution but not sure now :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove css classes from other_page.html which are conflicting with base page.

Best practice is that do not apply css classes for ajax pages (other_page.html is your ajax page as you are getting content of it by jquery load method) only get page content. And on main page write required classes for Ajax content.

This will resolve your problem

Comment: Thanks i know in theory how it should be done with CSS classes etc. Iframes are very good option - easy and it does what it should the only problem is browser support nowadays. I was hoping there are any easy work around. Appretiate your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

you should specify your css using child combinators:

```
body > div {…} /* affects only the div directly below the body tag */
body #target_div > div {…} /* affects the loaded content */
```